# Find group with given presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find the groups with presentation

a) $ < x, y  | x y^m > $

b) $ <x,y | xy^m , xy^n> $

It should be a "well-known" group.

---

I don't know what to do... I tried to write it explicitely but I don't get something nice. 
For the first one I get this: 
 $$ \{ y^{a} x^{i_1} y^{j_1} ... x^{i_k} y^{j_k} | k \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0 \} , i_s \neq 0, |j_s| <m , a \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{x^i| i \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

Comment: Note that the generators commute. That should help with the first one. For the second one, try playing around a bit with the two relations (for example setting them equal to each other).

Comment: For next time, use `\langle x, y \rangle` ("left angle" and "right angle" brackets) instead of `<x, y>`: $\langle x, y \rangle$ vs. $<x, y>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideas:

(a) Since $\;xy^m=1\implies x=y^{-m}\implies\;$ the group can be generated only by $\;y\;$ , so it is a cyclic group

b) Almost as before, but this time you get

$$y^m=y^n\implies |\langle y\rangle|<\infty\;\;\text{if}\;\;n\neq m$$